# Append partitioned Sheets & blend in the same Google Data Studio Data Source?

Tags: looker-studio

I am trying to blend data in Google Data Studios from 3 Google Sheet tabs:

1. History1 sheet, 5 years of data
2. History2 sheet, next 5 years of data (split for Sheets performance reasons, identical columns to #1)
3. Categories sheet, that maps to a Category field used in sheets 1 and 2

Sheets 1 & 2 represent the same logical table, just partitioned by date.

I am trying to import data into Google Studio such that

- a) History1 & History2 are re-aggregated and treated as a single data set
- b) History1 & History2's Category fields are joined to Categories.Category field

I can't seem to find a way to make this work. I think the append mode described in (a) is the root of the problem and doesn't appear to be supported. The UI seems to require me to join the same columns across all 3 sheets which won't work, and forces me to duplicate all the same-named columns as 2 different dimensions.
I can easily blend the Category sheet with a single other Google sheet, but not multiple.

Is there a way to append partitioned data & blend inside Google Data Studio?